# mysql order by with case not working

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

Please can anyone explain why isn´t sorting working?

Here is code example:

```
SET @orderBy = 0;
SET @isDescending = 1;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS orders;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE orders (ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, CreationDate DATETIME NOT NULL, CustomerID BIGINT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO orders VALUES(1, '2016/08/28', 2);
INSERT INTO orders VALUES(2, '2016/08/26', 2);
INSERT INTO orders VALUES(3, '2016/08/27', 2);

SELECT * FROM orders WHERE CustomerID = 2
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @orderBy = 0 AND @isDescending = 0 THEN
        CreationDate
    END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @orderBy = 0 AND @isDescending = 1 THEN
        CreationDate
    END DESC;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS orders;
```

See mysqlworkbench screenshot:

[image]

I cannot see any mistake in SQL code. I am using 5.7.12 and also 5.7.14 version. The sorting behaviour is random.

Thank you for reply.

Comment: Did not understand the logic behind this order by. You have some global variables and they never change within the query scope. Please provide some more information on it.

Comment: That is irrelevant. In real they are stored procedure´s parameters and they can change and in order by I have more case statements.

Comment: I test this on 5.6.28 - working properly.

Comment: I cannnot get this to fail either, have you tried from command line?

Comment: No, I did not. It´s strange. I am no longer able to simulate this behaviour in 5.7.14 version. However in 5.7.12 I am.
I have tried this in MS SQL and everything was fine. I think It´s (another) mysql bug.

Comment: I was able to reproduce it too, looks like a bug. First version it occured to me was 5.7.9. 5.7.8 and before worked as expected. To make your query work, I was able to use `else null` or `else cast(null as datetime)` (or some other value) JUST to the second `case` (adding it to the first `case` will break it again). I guess it is some kind of datatype problem with optimization (my first guess is some aftereffect of the `filesort` optimization from 5.7.3, though 5.7.3 itself seems to work).

Comment: Thank you. I reported this bug to mysql bugs center.